# Unity fails to compile project with firebase analytics because of Cocoapods

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to integrate `Firebase-Analytics` in my `Unity 2013.3.1` project.

After following the [integration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#prerequisites), I've tried to build the project.

However, Unity fails to build. The reason seems to be `cocoapods`.

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Analytics (= 4.8.1)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Analytics (= 4.8.1)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

I've tried to reinstall cocoapods and re-run `pod setup`, and also deleting the repo and re-setupping using `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`, but I had no success.

Here's the generated Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '4.8.1'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.8.1'
end
```

One last thing I've tried was to remove the specific version tags into the Podfile (I've removed the '4.8.1'). This fixed the `pod install`, however **I couldn't find a way to have a successfull build from unity, since the Podfile is auto-generated**.

Here's the pod install output after removing the version tag:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase (4.9.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.9)
Installing FirebaseCore (4.0.15)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.9)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.3)
Installing nanopb (0.3.8)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 6 total pods installed.
```

It looks like `FirebaseAnalytics` is currently at version 4.0.9, not 4.8.1.

Did anyone have similar issues?

Comment: two years later and this is still relevant. Why Google... why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to the [4.4.2 release](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#4.4.2).

Or to workaround with 4.4.1:

Manually edited each of *Dependencies.xml* files in Assets/Firebase/Editor to change the version from 4.8.1 to 4.8.2. Example:

```
  <iosPods>
  <!-- Mike changed this from 4.8.1 to 4.8.2 -->
    <iosPod name="Firebase/Analytics" version="4.8.2" minTargetSdk="7.0">
    </iosPod>
  </iosPods>
```

Reference and additional detail [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/4.8.1%7Csort:date/firebase-talk/iuGN46kHkKY/QDHQJ0ubAwAJ).

Answer (score 1):

The version of FirebaseAnalytics used by Firebase 4.9 is 4.0.9, not 4.8.1. [See the podspec for reference.](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json)

Another possible issue for failing is that your dependency (iOS 7) is too old and it's not supported by Xcode 9, nor by the latest version of Firebase.

Replace

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

with

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

Comment: I've tried to use 8.0, however it's still not working. `None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: Firebase/Analytics (= 4.8.1).`

Comment: Ok, this seems a problem in Unity. Indeed, the auto-generated Podfile is locked to `Firebase/Analytics 4.8.1`, even if the last version is `4.0.9`... uhm